# New to PIVOT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2000

I need help to find whether the below is achievable

I got a table for example

[image]

Is it possible to use the PIVOT sql command to convert it something like this 
If so could someone help me with it.

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: That's called UNpivot

Comment: Ok just found out my version is Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)  and can't use pivot command :(

Comment: Agree with GurV. A pivot would work if you are taking the second table and morphing it into the first, not the other way around. The first table is not normalized.

Comment: Any chance of upgrading SQL Server to something modern?  EOL was nearly 4 years ago...

Comment: Yes but that I cant make the decision it should be the boss..is there anyway doing this in 2000

Comment: Is that the full schema of your source table?  Or are there more QX columns?

Comment: there is another 10 more QX columns

Comment: on SQL 2000 you will need to do the unpivot by hand.  How many questions do you have?

Comment: got totally 15 questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without the [UNPIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) keyword you would have to do this transform by hand.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [D].[UID]
        ,'Q1' AS [Question]
        ,[D].[Q1_Score] AS [Score]
        ,[D].[Category]
    FROM [DataSet] AS [D]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        [D].[UID]
        ,'Q2' AS [Question]
        ,[D].[Q2_Score] AS [Score]
        ,[D].[Category]
    FROM [DataSet] AS [D]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        [D].[UID]
        ,'Q3' AS [Question]
        ,[D].[Q3_Score] AS [Score]
        ,[D].[Category]
    FROM [DataSet] AS [D]
) [upivot]
ORDER BY
    [UID]
    ,[Question]
```

... if you can use a new version of SQL with UNPIVOT then you can do this...

```
SELECT 
    [UID]
    ,SUBSTRING([Question],1,2) AS [Question]
    ,[Score]
    ,[Category]
FROM [DataSet]
UNPIVOT (
    [Score] FOR [Question] IN (
        [Q1_Score]
        ,[Q2_Score]
        ,[Q3_Score]
    )
) [upivot]
```

The results for either of the above is this...

```
UID Question    Score   Category
1   Q1              10  Science
1   Q2              7   Science
1   Q3              5   Science
2   Q1              9   Maths
2   Q2              6   Maths
2   Q3              10  Maths
3   Q1              0   History
3   Q2              3   History
3   Q3              4   History
4   Q1              3   English
4   Q2              1   English
4   Q3              4   English
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table using select with unions. If it needs to be the same table you could then drop the old one and create it from the new one.

```
select unique_id,'Q1' as 'Question', Q1_score as 'Score', Category
from table
union all
select unique_id,'Q2' as 'Question', Q2_score as 'Score', Category
from table
union all
select unique_id,'Q3' as 'Question', Q3_score as 'Score', Category
from table
order by unique_id, Question
```

--changed the group by to order by per Matthew Whited

Comment: you are going to need a subquery and are few aggragate functions to use that group by

Answer (score 0):

In this post of mine from just the other day, I demonstrate that the complex UNION ALL SELECT-s as seen above are not necessary - if you CROSS JOIN with an in-line table consisting of as many consecutive integers as you have horizontal columns to un-pivot. It works on any database that supports CROSS JOIN and the CASE .. WHEN clause:

[How to create multiple rows from a initial row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619066/how-to-create-multiple-rows-from-a-initial-row/41619360#41619360)

vertical pivoting and "un-pivoting" mean the same.

And here, I take it to extremes:

[Vertica - Is there LATERAL VIEW functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705184/vertica-is-there-lateral-view-functionality/41746460#41746460)

In this post, I un-pivot a two-row table, then do something with the pivoted data, and then re-pivot it.

Happy playing ..